# High quality spell checker which works **online**

Tags: spell-check

Grammarly is a great spell checker.

Unfortunately the have no simple way to check text online (without chrome extension)

Is there a high quality spell checker which works online?

I would even pay for it.

Answer (score 0):

After you have registered at Grammarly you get a text area where you can check our spelling. Works fine.